# Add Product Cat when Auction time ended And Removing all Categorys from a Woocommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am want to add a Product cat to my Woocommerce product when the time is 0 so I can show these items in a different section.

I made the category "Auction ended" that I want to add to the product.

The code works but I still keeps displaying the product in a carousel where it shouldn't be.

I think I need to remove all current categorys before and then only having the "Auction ended" category.

```php
function auction_end_date_countdown() {


        global $product;
        
        $product      = apply_filters( 'yith_wcact_get_auction_product', $product );

        ob_start();

        if ( 'auction' === $product->get_type() ) { 

                                    $dateclose = $product->get_end_date();
                                    
                                    if ( $dateclose ) {
                                    
                                        $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");                                   
                                        $format_date = get_option( 'yith_wcact_general_date_format', 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
                                        
                                        $format = $format_date . ' ' . $format_time;
                                        
                                        $date = ( date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateclose ) );
                                                                            
                                        $diff = abs(strtotime($today) - strtotime($date));



                                        if ($today < $date) {
                                            echo $date;
                                        }else{
                                            echo $today;
                                            
                                            
                                                global $product;

                                                $term_name = 'Auction ended';

                                                // Get the product category term Id for "Sold out" term name
                                                $term_id   = get_term_by( 'name', $term_name, 'product_cat' )->term_id;

                                                   // Get product categories (if there is any)
                                                   $term_ids = (array) $product->get_category_ids();

                                                   // Add the product category term Id for "Sold out" term name to $term_ids array
                                                   $term_ids[] = $term_id;

                                                   $product->set_category_ids( $term_ids ); // Update product categories
                                                   $product->save(); // Save to database
                                                 
                                            
                                            }
                                        
                                                    
                                        
                                        
                                    }
                                     

        }

        $html = ob_get_clean();
        return $html;


        
}
add_shortcode( 'veiling_eind_datum_aftellen', 'auction_end_date_countdown' );
```

Comment: you could probably add something like this to your code right before adding the new category $terms = get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');
foreach($terms as $term){
    wp_remove_object_terms($product_id, $term->term_id, 'product_cat');
}

Comment: Yea just found it out and needed to tweak some things. But its working :)

Comment: Ahh I was just typing an answer for you haha. Good thing you sorted it out :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Add the Product category "Auction ended" and not display it in certain carousel/rosters I needed to remove all categorys and then adding the category I wanted to add. (I my case )

```php
                                                global $product;
                                            
                                                $product->set_category_ids( array() ); // Remove all categories from product
                                                $term_name = 'Afgelopen veiling';

                                                // Get the product category term Id for "" term name
                                                $term_id   = get_term_by( 'name', $term_name, 'product_cat' )->term_id;

                                                   // Get product categories (if there is any)
                                                   $term_ids = (array) $product->get_category_ids();

                                                   // Add the product category term Id for "Sold out" term name to $term_ids array
                                                   $term_ids[] = $term_id;

                                                   $product->set_category_ids( $term_ids ); // Update product categories
                                                   $product->save(); // Save to database
```